# convert txt with empty lines in csv

Tags: shell, csv, type-conversion, txt

I have many files like the following:

```
cat test.data
name1
...
nameN

title1
...
titleM

abstract1
...
abstractO

ID
```

where the numbers N,M,O differ from file to file. But in all files the fields are separated by empty lines. I want to transform these data into csv, each file into a line with the rows (name, title, abtract, ID) like this:

`name1 ...nameN|title1 ... titleM|abstract1 ... abstractO|ID`

I have tried with awk and sed, but failed. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if a columne (eg. title or abstract) contains `|` ?

Comment: _I have tried with awk and sed, but failed._  It's hard to correct your attempts, if you don't show them.....

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name 'test*.data' |
xargs awk -v n=$N -v t=$M -v a=$O '
   BEGIN {
      # lines to ignore
      x[ i+=(n+1) ]
      x[ i+=(t+1) ]
      x[ i+=(a+1) ]

      # number of lines per file
      ++i
   }
   !(FNR in x) {
      printf("%s%s", $0, FNR<i?"|":"\n")
   }
' >>out.csv
```

- define `N`, `M`, `O` appropriately
- assumes data does not contain the separator character `|`
- assumes `out.csv` is pre-filled with suitable header line

Answer (score 0):

Given `file`:

```
name1
name2
name3

title1
title2

abstract1
abstract2
abstract3
abstract4

ID
```

then

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = "\n"; RS = ""}
  {
    record = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) record = record "," $i
    printf "%s%s", sep, record
    sep = "|"
  }
  END {printf "\n"}
' file
```

outputs

```
name1,name2,name3|title1,title2|abstract1,abstract2,abstract3,abstract4|ID
```

This uses `RS = ""` which treats sequences of blank lines as **record** separators, and `FS = "\n"` which treats newlines as **field** separators.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect! You save me the day.